# Why i get errors, putting SeekBar on widget layout?

Tags: xml, android

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android           = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id          = "@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height       = "fill_parent" 
    android:background      = "@drawable/widget_background" 
    android:layout_gravity      = "left"
    >

        <SeekBar
            android:layout_width        = "fill_parent"
            android:layout_height       = "wrap_content"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get "Problem loading widget"
Why this layout doestn't work?

02-25 15:16:20.904: WARN/ResourceType(57): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000

02-25 15:16:21.003: WARN/ResourceType(57): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001

02-25 15:16:21.664: WARN/ResourceType(57): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060000

02-25 15:16:21.673: WARN/ResourceType(57): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f060001

02-25 15:16:21.753: WARN/ResourceType(57): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f030000

02-25 15:16:32.083: WARN/AppWidgetHostView(102): Error inflating AppWidget AppWidgetProviderInfo(provider=ComponentInfo{myPackage.myApp/myPackage.myApp.MyClass}): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class android.widget.SeekBar

Comment: Does 'widget_background' exist under drawable ?

Comment: yes, also i tested this layout not with SeekBar, but with TextView and all worked. Also android layout editot viewing SeekBar fine, but in emulator widget showing "Problem Loading Winget"

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post

[Android: Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188025/android-resources-dont-contain-package-for-resource-number-0x)

Are you trying to reference these resources from java code, or just load them from setContentView?