# Android: Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x

Tags: java, android, eclipse, resources, adt

I'm writing on a custom view in android. It uses some png's, provided as resources in the drawable-folder (I put it in all of the drawable folders now, just to make sure) of my project.

Unfortunately, when I startup the app, I get a force close and the last thing the log says is: `"WARN/ResourceType(261): Resources don't contain package for resource number 0x7f020002"` (The Hex-Number is the first icon I intend to load).

Now for the curious thing: The graphical layout-editor of the eclipse adt plugin has no problems whatsoever loading an displaying the icons in its design view. It's only when I start up the actual app (emulator or actual cellphone), that android can't find the resources.

I tried cleaning the project and refreshing the file structure. That didn't quite work out -.-

EDIT: I just realized that I can't even load a string resource. The problem seems to exist for all resources. Do I have to do something, before the resources become available?

Hope someone can help me,

thx in advance

Comment: Does the error occur on the emulator or only the physical device?

Comment: It's in the emulator and on the physical device

Comment: You could try looking at your R.java file and see what 0x7f020002 is. That might give you a clue of where to look.

Comment: I already did that, it's the first icon I intend to load. It's definitely in the drawable folder.

Comment: Is it in all the drawable folders? Like HDPI,MDPI?

Comment: yep, it definitely is. It's the same icon in every folder for now, but that doesn't matter, does it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

kk, this year's dumbness awards go to me. I was using `Resources.getSystem().get...` instead of `this.getContext().getResources().get...`

thx to all of you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Some times when adding resource files to res dir, the generated R class gets out of sync with its assets. If you are compiling on the command line with ant, try navigating to where build scripts are and doing a clean build:

```
ant clean
```

I don't really know much about eclipse, but there might be a way to tell eclipse to refresh generated files.

Comment: No, I'm not building with ant. But I did an "eclipsish" clean and that didn't work. I even deleted the R.java file and eclipse immediately recreated it. However, that didn't do the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in v2.1 Emulator, while the same app runs smoothly in 1.5,1.6,2.3.x and 4.x AVDs.

I am using library in my project.The resource number was not even in R.java file. So, ultimately I found that the resource id was in some other package's R file, which had no relation to my project. After deleting this project and Cleaning the projects, my app loaded smoothly :)